# Webots Sim "ready" signal

Tags: webots

When using an external python script to start webots (or when restarting an environment) it would be necessary to know when the simulation is ready, for an external controller to (re-)run.

Is there any sort of "ready" signal that webots returns after starting from the commandline or when restarting a world ? Or other ways to probe when the external controller can start working ?

Answer (score 2):

Webots doesn't provide such signal directly. However, when Webots is started, it will create in the temporary files a folder called `webots-XXXX` (one per instance of Webots, `XXXX` should be replaced by the PID of the Webots process) and in this folder, a file called `WEBOTS_SERVER` will be created as soon as the controllers are ready to be started